# Delete a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to figure out a way of deleting (dynamically) subplots in matplotlib. I see they have a `remove` method, but I get the error

```
NotImplementedError: cannot remove artist
```

I'm surprised that I can't find this anywhere.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)

axs[0].plot([1,2],[3,4])
axs[2].plot([0,1],[2,3])

plt.draw()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use [`fig.delaxes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.delaxes) or [`plt.delaxes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.delaxes.html) to remove unwanted subplots

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)
axs[0].plot([1,2],[3,4])
axs[2].plot([0,1],[2,3])

fig.delaxes(axs[1])

plt.draw()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! And how to get rid of the empty space in between the subplots now, and let two plots fill all the window width? tight_layout() doesn't work properly for me...

Answer (score 32):

```
ax.set_visible(False)
```

will suffice in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the axis from the figure [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.remove.html):

```
axs[1].remove()
```